# Passing dynamic value to kafka consumer topic at runtime for message driven channel adapter

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration

Requirement is to set the **topics** attribute below at runtime **without restarting the server**.How can we achieve it here.
Currently we are reading the value from the properties file but here it require the server restart to reflect the changes done .

example:
sample.properties(inside the deployment directory)

**topic.list=topic1,topic2**

and would like to consume from topic3 in future without server restart.

**NOTE** : find that the **topics** is a **final** variable.

tried reading the key(topic.list) from the file system path (outside the deployment directory) but no luck.

Any suggestion.

```
<int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter

               id="inAdapter"
               channel="fromKafka"
               connection-factory="connectionFactory"
               key-decoder="kafkaKeyDecoder"
               payload-decoder="kafkaDecoder"                              
               topics="${topic.list}"
               offset-manager="offsetManager"/>
```

Comment: How often would you be changing topics? there is always a way (dynamic creation of the channel adapter in this case)  a bit long though, it would need some external intervention as well (could be an api call to trigger the action)

Comment: Not quite often.However it is a requirement to have the flexibility.Would be great,f you can please guide me on this direction.

Comment: try to understand this the concept here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp then you can easily customize to fit your use-case and I can help should you've followups

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Java DSL to dynamically add adapters for additional topics on demand...

```
@Autowired
private IntegrationFlowContext flowContext;

public void addAnotherListenerForTopics(String... topics) {
    IntegrationFlow flow =
        IntegrationFlows.from(Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(consumerFactory(), topics))
            .channel("fromKafka")
            .get();
    this.flowContext.registration(flow).register();
}
```

and

```
bean.addAnotherListenerForTopics("added.new");
```

pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-integration-java-dsl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that if you are using broker partition assignment, the new container needs a different group id to avoid revoking the existing assignments.

Comment: Can you please explain the theory behind this solution more in detail for a better undertsanding?

Comment: I am not sure what you are having trouble understanding; dynamic flow registration is covered in [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2016/09/27/java-dsl-for-spring-integration-1-2-release-candidate-1-is-available). Ask a new question if there's something else you need.

Comment: Please have a look into this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46400329/how-to-pass-topics-dynamically-to-a-kafka-listener