# How to pass topics dynamically to a kafka listener?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

From a couple of days I'm trying out ways to dynamically pass topics to Kafka listener rather than using them through keys from a Java DSL. Anyone around done this before or could throw some light on what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot "dynamically pass topics to Kafka listener "; you have to programmatically create a listener container instead.

Comment: Thank you, I had the same opinion. However, It would be very helpful if you could post a code snippet on how to do it.

Comment: Just create a new `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` (or `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer`) and `start()` it.

Comment: Start where? My consumer now is a POJO listener with @KafkaListener, There's a ConsumerConfig file where i write my consumer configs. Same file has containerFactory and a container, But KafkaListener annotation doesn't accept the container as a parameter. Where do i use this container object and start it?

Comment: You can't create `@KafkaListener` programmatically; just the underlying listener container with a regular `MessageListener`. You could create a `@KafkaListener` programmatically, if you load it into a new `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: Yes, I will create a MessageListener programmatically in my consumer config file but how would the application know that this is the consumer listening to the topics? Is there a code posted for this somewhere that i can refer?

Comment: Sorry; I don't understand the question; to consume from a new topic; simply create a new container, configure it and call `start()`.

Comment: Creation and Config of container:

    @Bean 
    public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container() throws Exception { 
      ContainerProperties properties = new ContainerProperties(this.topics); // set more properties
      properties.setPauseEnabled(true);
      properties.setPauseAfter(0);
         return new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(consumerFactory(), properties); 
    }

Comment: Starting of container:

    @Bean
    public void startContainer(){KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = container();
     container.start();
     
    }

Am i right?

Comment: Don't put code in comments; it's hard to read; edit the question instead. Yes, it looks correct.

Comment: Sure, will do! Now i assume that the listener has started, How do i access the record posted by the producer onto the queue using this container? Similar to listener(ConsumerRecord<?,?> record) usinf @KafkaListener?

Comment: `containerProperties.setMessageListener(myListener)`. Where `myListener` implements one of the [listener interfaces](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#message-listeners).

Comment: Thanks a ton @Gary, It worked like a charm. Please bear with me for some more time and have a look at this one too:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447119/how-to-pause-a-kafka-consumer/46447801#46447801

Comment: In the above discussed implementation, if I use ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer, is there any possible way to consume messages in a batch?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments; especially when the answer is 4 years old; the framework has moved on since then. Yes,  `setBatchListener(true)` on the container factory. If you need more help, ask a new question.

Comment: If you are creating the container yourself, just inject a BatchMessageListener; if you are using a container factory to create the container, setBatchListener(true) on the factory so that it will use the correct adapter.

Answer (score 16):

The easiest solution I found was to use SpEL:

```
@Autowired
private SomeBean kafkaTopicNameProvider;

@KafkaListener(topics = "#{kafkaTopicNameProvider.provideName()}")
public void listener() { ... }
```

Comment: thanks. Alternatively topics may come via application.yml prop: `@KafkaListener(topics = {"${someprop}"})`

Comment: What is more, `kafkaTopicNameProvider.provideName()` can also return a `String[]` and allow to configure multiple topics using a single `SpEL`

Comment: if your class name is "SomeBean" and want to access it in SpEL, "#{someBean.field}". note its lower case.

Answer (score 4):

**Here is a working solution:**

```
// Start brokers without using the "@KafkaListener" annotation
Map<String, Object> consumerProps = consumerProps("my-srv1:9092", "my-group", "false");
DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, String> cf = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerProps);
ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties("my-topic");
KafkaMessageListenerContainer container = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(cf, containerProperties);
final BlockingQueue<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> records = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
container.setupMessageListener((MessageListener<String, String>) record -> {
    log.error("Message received: " + record);
    records.add(record);
});
container.start();

/**
 * Set up test properties for an {@code <Integer, String>} consumer.
 * @param brokersCommaSep the bootstrapServers property (comma separated servers).
 * @param group the group id.
 * @param autoCommit the auto commit.
 * @return the properties.
 */
public static Map<String, Object> consumerProps(String brokersCommaSep, String group, String autoCommit) {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokersCommaSep);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, group);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, autoCommit);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "10");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 60000);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    return props;
}
```

Hope it can help.

Answer (score 3):

I made kafka listener for runtime registration, de-registration, start, stop.

```
public class KafkaListener {

     private final KafkaListenerContainerFactory kafkaListenerContainerFactory;
     private final Map<String, MessageListenerContainer> registeredTopicMap;

/** Kafka listener registration at runtime.**/
public void register(final Supplier<Set<String>> topicSupplier, final Supplier<MessageListener> messageListenerSupplier) {

    synchronized (lock) {
        final Set<String> registeredTopics = getRegisteredTopics();
        final Set<String> topics = topicSupplier.get();

        if (topics.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        topics.stream()
                .filter(topic -> !registeredTopics.contains(topic))
                .forEach(topic -> doRegister(topic, messageListenerSupplier.get()));
    }
}


private void doRegister(final String topic, final MessageListener messageListener) {
    final MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer = kafkaListenerContainerFactory.createContainer(topic);
    messageListenerContainer.setupMessageListener(messageListener);
    messageListenerContainer.start();

    registeredTopicMap.put(topic, messageListenerContainer);
}
```

---

Full source code
: https://github.com/pkgonan/kafka-listener

First, try it.

```
docker-compose up -d
```

And then. call api.

```
curl -XPOST /consumers/order/register .....

curl -XPOST /consumers/order/de-register .....

curl -XPOST /consumers/order/stop

curl -XPOST /consumers/order/start
```

Answer (score 1):

you can  change Topics at runtime  dynamicly!!!!

```
@Component
public class StoppingErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;

    @Override
    public void handle(Exception thrownException, ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record) {
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = (ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer)kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("fence");
        ContainerProperties cp=listenerContainer.getContainerProperties();
        String[] topics =cp.getTopics();
        topics[0]="gaonb";
        listenerContainer.stop();
        listenerContainer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it doesn't work: getTopics() returns a copy of the topics array

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone looking to build a module which can be used as a library, do checkout https://github.com/313hemant313/TheGameKafka

Based on clientName we can get KafkaProducer and KafkaConsumer, sample usage:

```
TheGameKafkaProducer<String, String> theGameKafkaProducer = theGameKafkaProducerFactory.getTheGameKafkaProducer(
    "testClient");
theGameKafkaProducer.send("this is a test msg from TheGameKafkaProducer");

TheGameKafkaConsumer<String, String> theGameKafkaConsumer = theGameKafkaConsumerFactory.getTheGameKafkaConsumer(
    "testClient");
theGameKafkaConsumer.listen(messageListener());

private MessageListener<String, String> messageListener() {
  return rec -> log.info("TheGameKafkaConsumer listened : {}", rec);
}
```

Sample config:

```
the-game-kafka:
  clientConsumerProperties:
    - clientName: "testClient"
      topic: "testTopic"
      enabled: true
      kafkaProperties:
        consumer:
          bootstrapServers: localhost:9094
          groupId: "tgk-group"
          autoOffset: earliest
          keyDeserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
          value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
          properties:
            spring:
              json:
                trusted:
                  packages: "*"
              deserializer:
                value:
                  delegate:
                    class: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
  clientProducerProperties:
    - clientName: "testClient"
      topic: "testTopic"
      enabled: true
      kafkaProperties:
        producer:
          bootstrapServers: localhost:9094
```

Inspired by https://github.com/pkgonan/kafka-listener.